# Force 1080i VGA on hdmi output

Tags: hdmi, video, kodi

I have a Pioneer rear projection TV that only allows HD in the form of a VGA connector and ONLY 1080i.

I am going out of the Pi in HDMI into an HDMI to VGA adapter box shown [here on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003O55U8K).

I have in the `config.txt` the following:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=5
arm_freq=850
core_freq=375
force_turbo=1
disable_overscan=1
gpu_mem=128
start_file=start_x.elf
fixup_file=fixup_x.dat
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
#hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1
```

When the pi starts to boot, I see the Logo in what seems to be in 1080i clearly and stable, then as it continues to boot everything goes nuts as if it is going into a resolution that is not supported by my tv.

I then tried to boot with the same config on my samsung plasma and it does indeed start in 1080i, then drops back to 640x480.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `tvservice -s` output?

Comment: Try adding `hdmi_group=1` and `hdmi_mode=5` to your `config.txt`.  Or try using the command `tvservice -e "CEA 5"` which should make the same settings.  See http://elinux.org/RPiconfig for more info on hdmi_group and hdmi_mode.

Answer (score 2):

When you connected your samsung plasma, did you connect it to the hdmi->vga converter? If so, try

```
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
```

in `config.txt`. Maybe the converter box sends out a wrong edid information to the pi.

(The product rating at amazon is 50% good and 50% bad, maybe you got one of the bad ones.)

Comment: Actually, I connected to the samsung plasma through HDMI only. I see the tv reporting 1080 60i at bootup, then after the logo's finish the tv then reports 640x480 60p

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a noobs based install? if so it sounds like you may have the correct video settings in the config.txt on the recovery partition but not in the config.txt on the boot partition for the individual operating system.